# How to make inotifywait runs command in queue?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, monitoring, inotifywait, rclone

How to make inotifywait runs command in queue?

According to this script that moves file automatically right after it is created

```
cd "a specific folder"
inotifywait -me close_write --format %f . | while read file
do  
    rclone move "$file" …
done
```

In case that multiple files are created at the same time or gradually how to make them(the transfer) run in queue?

Comment: They are already transfered in a queue.

Comment: Why are you using `inotify` for this in the first place? After  the `while` loop, all commands are done

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the **specific name** of the file that you are expecting to be "dropped" in the folder, if you want to control the sequence of actions. Otherwise (*for monitor on directory*), you need to accept that they might be out of order and deal with the names as they "**pop up**" for a chosen "**end action**".